# Keep original index of 2D Arraylist using comparable class

Tags: java, arraylist, comparable

I have an arraylist of arraylists which stores distances between points. I need to keep the original indexes of the distances after sorting the arraylist, because I need to find the K-nearest neighbours at a later stage of the code. The class I have implemented does not output the correct index of the distances instead an index of the arraylists only is the output

I have tried implementing a 2D comparable class but I was given a few errors.

```
public staticArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>distance(ArrayList<sample_points> points) {

    ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> distArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>(points.size());
    double dist = 0;
    List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();
    for(int i = 0; i<points.size()-1; i++) {
        ArrayList<Double> distances = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for(int j=i+1; j<points.size(); j++){
            // do your calculations here
            dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(points.get(i).getX() - points.get(j).getX(), 2) 
                    + Math.pow(points.get(i).getY() - points.get(j).getY(), 2));   
            distances.add(dist);// add the distance to the current distances list
        }
        distArray.add(distances);//
    }
    System.out.print("Distances: "distArray);
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i < distArray.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < distArray.get(i).size(); j++) {
            elements.add(new Element(i, distArray.get(i).get(j)));
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(elements);
    for(int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Dist "+ elements.get(i).distance + " " 
                + "Index " + elements.get(i).index+" ");
    }
}
```

Here is my comparable class:

```
class Element implements  Comparable<Element>{
    public final int index;
    public final double distance;

    public Element(int index, double distance){
        this.index = index;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Element e){
        return   Double.valueOf(this.distance).compareTo(Double.valueOf(e.distance));
    }
}
```

Expected results:

```
Distances: [[2.8284271247461903, 5.830951894845301, 7.280109889280518], 
[3.1622776601683795, 5.0], [2.23606797749979]]

Dist 2.23606797749979 Index 0 
Dist 2.8284271247461903 Index 0 
Dist 3.1622776601683795 Index 0 
Dist 5.0 Index 1 
Dist 5.830951894845301 Index 1 
Dist 7.280109889280518 Index 2
```

Actual results:

```
Distances: [[2.8284271247461903, 5.830951894845301, 7.280109889280518], 
[3.1622776601683795, 5.0], [2.23606797749979]]

Dist 2.23606797749979 Index 2 
Dist 2.8284271247461903 Index 0 
Dist 3.1622776601683795 Index 1 
Dist 5.0 Index 1 
Dist 5.830951894845301 Index 0 
Dist 7.280109889280518 Index 0
```

Comment: Consider formatting that all-left-justified code. If it is easier to read, it is easier to understand.

Comment: OK, I have tried formatting your code and output for you, but in the future, we would all appreciate it if you did this yourself when posting your question.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am new to stack overflow please bear with me

Comment: You don't appear to be debugging things correctly -- why not print out the indices when and where you create them? This to me seems the most likely code at fault, *not* your sorting code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On review of your code, I think that the error is in your assumptions and that the output itself is in fact correct. The index that you're seeing is in fact the index of the outer Lists within your list of list nested array lists that you create here:

```
for (int i=0; i<points.size()-1; i++) {
    ArrayList<Double> distances = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (int j=i+1; j < points.size(); j++) {
        // do your calculations here
        dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(points.get(i).getX() - points.get(j).getX(), 2) 
                + Math.pow(points.get(i).getY() - points.get(j).getY(), 2));   
        distances.add(dist); // add the distance to the current distances list
    }
    distArray.add(distances);  //  ***** the index of items added here *****
}
```

If you add these debugging lines:

```
for (int i=0; i < points.size()-1; i++) {
    ArrayList<Double> distances = new ArrayList<Double>();
    for (int j=i+1; j<points.size(); j++) {
        // do your calculations here
        dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(points.get(i).getX() - points.get(j).getX(), 2) 
                + Math.pow(points.get(i).getY() - points.get(j).getY(), 2));   
        distances.add(dist);// add the distance to the current distances list
    }
    distArray.add(distances);  //  ***** the index of items added here *****

    // ******* add this  ********
    System.out.println(distArray.indexOf(distances));
    System.out.println(distances);
    System.out.println();
}
```

You'll see that this is correct. You need to either change how you create your index values or change your assumptions.

---

Also, your Element index fields are *immutable* and are being created *before* any items in the distance ArrayList are sorted, and so this field cannot represent the sort order of distances.

---

You state in comment:

> If I have a 2D Arraylist of distances i.e [ [d1,d2,d3], [d4,d5], [d6] ]. The indices will be as follows d1=0, d2 =1, d3 = 2, d4 =0, d5 =1 and d6 =0. So I need to get the original indices as mentioned after I sort each arraylist.

Then use `j` to create the index, not `i`

```
for(int i = 0; i < distArray.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < distArray.get(i).size(); j++) {
        // elements.add(new Element(i, distArray.get(i).get(j)));
        elements.add(new Element(j, distArray.get(i).get(j))); // ***** note change *****
    }
}
```

---

Side note: in the future, create a minimal runnable program that demonstrates the problem, that we can compile and run easily. For this question I had to create one myself:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Foo01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<SamplePoints> points = new ArrayList<>();

        int maxXY = 100;
        int max = 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            int x = (int) (maxXY * Math.random());
            int y = (int) (maxXY * Math.random());
            points.add(new SamplePoints(x, y));
        }

        distance(points);
    }

    private static class SamplePoints {
        private int x;
        private int y;

        public SamplePoints(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getX() {
            return x;
        }

        public int getY() {
            return y;
        }

    }

    private static class Element implements Comparable<Element> {
        public final int index;
        public final double distance;

        public Element(int index, double distance) {
            this.index = index;
            this.distance = distance;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Element e) {
            return Double.valueOf(this.distance).compareTo(Double.valueOf(e.distance));
        }
    }

    public static void distance(List<SamplePoints> points) {

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> distArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>(points.size());
        double dist = 0;
        List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();
        for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; i++) {
            ArrayList<Double> distances = new ArrayList<Double>();
            for (int j = i + 1; j < points.size(); j++) {
                // do your calculations here
                dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(points.get(i).getX() - points.get(j).getX(), 2)
                        + Math.pow(points.get(i).getY() - points.get(j).getY(), 2));
                distances.add(dist);// add the distance to the current distances
                                    // list
            }
            distArray.add(distances);//

            System.out.println(distArray.indexOf(distances));
            System.out.println(distances);
            System.out.println();

        }
        System.out.print("Distances: " + distArray);
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < distArray.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < distArray.get(i).size(); j++) {
                elements.add(new Element(i, distArray.get(i).get(j)));
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(elements);
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Dist " + elements.get(i).distance + " " + "Index "
                    + elements.get(i).index + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

But in the future, you'll want to do this to help make your question easier to answer.

Comment: Thanks, I need to get the index values of the distances within the arraylist instead of the indices of the outer arraylists.

Comment: @D.Khumalo: please explain what you need in greater detail and clarity, and edit this information into your question.

Comment: @D.Khumalo: see edit: your index field is immutable, and  you're setting it before any items have been sorted, so this can never represent what it seems you want it to represent.

Comment: If I have a 2D Arraylist of distances i.e [ [d1,d2,d3], [d4,d5], [d6] ]. The indices will be as follows d1=0, d2 =1, d3 = 2, d4 =0, d5 =1 and d6 =0. So I need to get the original indices as mentioned after I sort each arraylist.

Comment: @D.Khumalo: then use `j` to create the index, not `i`. See edit.

Comment: @D.Khumalo: again, it's all about debugging the *source* of the problem, which is *where you create the indices* for your Element objects.

Comment: Yes I have ran the code and it now works. Thank you so much. I just had a dumb moment there.

Comment: @D.Khumalo: you're welcome. Please see edit regarding creating of a [mre], and that includes *my* [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that I used to help debug your problem. Good luck!